# CMakelists.txt for compiling HDF5?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, hdf5

I am trying to compile a simple program to read a HDF5 file. The code compiles  correctly with h5c++. However I need a cmakelists.txt for the same

readdata.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
    using namespace H5;
#endif
const H5std_string FILE_NAME( "testfile.h5" );

int main (void)
{
    H5File openFile( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY );
}
```

I tried a cmakelists for it but it didnt work. It gave "not defined errors"

```
readdata.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT'
readdata.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT'
readdata.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `H5check_version'
readdata.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `H5::H5File::H5File(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)'
readdata.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `H5::H5File::~H5File()'
```

CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0) 
PROJECT (readhdf5)

find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable( readdata readdata.cpp )

target_link_libraries( readdata ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
```

If i put the HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES and HDF5_LIBRARIES manually the it works.

```
target_link_libraries( readdata libhdf5.so libhdf5_cpp.so)
```

So it is not able to read $HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES and $HDF5_LIBRARIES.How can I fix this?

Comment: Prefer `target_include_directories`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you attempt to compile depends on the HDF5 C++ bindings, which are not searched for by CMake's HDF5 module by default. Explicitly add the binding to the `find_package` command:

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX)
```